# How to exclude 1 when running the function?

Tags: r

The question is:
There is a package with a function that enables you to check if a number is prime. install.packages("schoolmath") library(schoolmath) is.prim(3)
Create a function that takes in two integers (set default values of 1 to both). The function should calculate the number of prime numbers between the two values.
My code is:

```
install.packages("schoolmath") 
library(schoolmath) 
is.prim(3)

prime <- function(x)
{

    p <- 0
    p1 <- ifelse(is.prim(x) == "TRUE", p + 1, p)
    return(sum(p1 == 1))
   }
prime(seq(1,10,1))
```

When I ran the function, it counts 1 as a prime number as well, which is not true. How to efficiently exclude that from the function?

Comment: `ifelse(x>1  & is.prim(x) == TRUE, p + 1, p)`  ?   BTW,   "TRUE" is not the same as TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your function a little because `is.prim` works with vectors and looking at the documentation for `sum` function:

> Logical true values are regarded as one, false values as zero.

Here is a function that counts the primes in a vector

```
count.primes <- function(x) {
   sum(x > 1 & is.prim(x))
}
```

Example:

```
count.primes(1:10)
# [1] 4

count.primes(1:20)
# [1] 8
```